# How does the following statement work?

Tags: java

```
int x = 10;
x += x++;

System.out.println(x);
```

why the answer of above statement is 20 ?

Comment: Doesn't matter why or how it works, it's hideous code and the creator should be beaten to death with a COBOL program printout.

Comment: But apart from that, what did you expect and why?

Comment: -1 for lack of visible effort on your part.

Answer (score 3):

The operator += is an addition assignment operator. Like Alya said above, `x += x++` is equivalent to `x = x + x++`, which in your case is `x = 10 + 10`. However, it's a very messy statement and I'll explain why towards the end of this post.

Now, you're probably thinking "Why is it 20 and not 21 (10 + 11) since you have the ++?" and that's valid. There's actually a difference between a post-increment and a pre-increment. x++ is the post-increment and will actually evaluate the value of x first and THEN increment x, while ++x is the pre-increment which will increment x and THEN evaluate the value of x.

For example, `x = 10; System.out.println(x++); System.out.println(x);` will print 10 and then print 11 because the first print line prints `x` and THEN performs the ++ calculation, making `x` 11 which the next line prints. Conversely, `x = 10; System.out.println(++x); System.out.println(x);` will print 11 on both print statements.

Going back to why I said `x += x++;` is very messy is because technically the ++ operator isn't performed in this case. `x++` is technically the same as `x=x+1` and remembering that x+=y is the same as x = x+y) , the line `x += x++;` is kind of like saying `x = x + (x = x + 1);` which is kind of weird looking because you do 2 assignment statements in one and won't actually "work how you want it". Back to your example `int x = 10; x += x++;` if you print x, you will get 20 even though you could look at it as: x is now the value of x + the value of x, then finally + 1 to it. But unfortunately, that's not how it works.

To solve your problem, if you change your code from a post-increment to a pre-increment, then it should work, ie: `x+=++x;` will print your 11 but I would argue the that's quite unreadable and a bit confusing. `x+=x; x++; System.out.println(x);` is easier to follow.

Answer (score 2):

`x++` will execute first. It returns `x` and then increments `x` by `1`.

Finally, the `+=` operator will add to `x` the return value of `x++`, which was `10`.

Thus, `x` will be `20` and it will overwrite the changes to `x` by the statement `x++`.

Answer (score 2):

So first `x` is initialized to be `10`.  Then the `x++` has higher precedence so that gets carried out first.  the "`++`" is a post-increment in this case (because it is after the variable as opposed to pre-increment which would be `++x`).  Post-increment means "first use the variable then increment it by one" so in this case it first uses `x` to be `10` then increments it to 11 after it is used.  Then we look at the "`+=`" which is short hand for "`x = x+x++`".  so we have `x = 10+10` which = `20`.  If you were to carry this out again it would equal `x = 20+20 = 40`.

In this particular case, the `x++` isn't necessary as `x` is reassigned the value after it is incremented each time.

Answer (score 1):

int x = 10; x += x++;

will equal to    x=x+x

where `x++` mean use the `x` value then increament it , so it's value will be 10

so the result will equal `20`

---

if you want to see the change of the `x` , see this example:

```
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    y +=x++;
    System.out.println(y);
    System.out.println(x);
```

will print :

```
y=20
x=11////////////according to x++ and without to overwrite it
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//
// Shows how increments work.
//
int i = 0;
System.out.println(i);

i++; // Add one
System.out.println(i);

i += 2; // Add two
System.out.println(i);

    i += 3; // Add three
System.out.println(i);

++i; // Add one
System.out.println(i);

i += i; // Added itself
System.out.println(i);

//
// Uses increments and assigns.
//
int v = 0;
v = i++; // Increment after value copy
System.out.println(v);
System.out.println(i);

v = ++i; // Increment before value copy
System.out.println(v);
System.out.println(i);
```

//Output

0       -
1
3
6
7
14
14
15
16
16

Comment: Rolled back [invalid edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2009560)

Answer (score 0):

```
  x+=x++ first assigns the value to x and then increments (post-increment)
  x+=++x first increments then assign the value to x (pre increment)
```

there are two types of increments/decrements in programming

```
  1. pre-increment/decrement
  2. post-increment/decrement
```

In programming both of these have same operations but differ in there nature as they both used for increment or decrement; they can be written as,

```
  x+=1; (increment by 1)
  x-=1; (decrement by 1)
```

you can use a variable instead in the above cases as well